# Mapping custom domain to GCP API Gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-api-gateway

I've set up an api using GCP API Gateway to map api calls to multiple Cloud Run services but now I need to point a custom domain to the API gateway. I see that there's no option to do so like in Cloud Run and I also tried setting a CNAME record pointing to the gateway's url but I didn't work.

Is their anyway I can set the domain name of the gateway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As advised on the relevant section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/deployment-model#configuring_a_domain_name_server):

> Custom domain names are not supported for API Gateway. If you want to customize the domain name, you have to create a load balancer to use your custom domain name and then direct requests to the gateway.dev domain of your deployed API.

Comment: it is unbelievealb that google is blocking every service they have from letting us using a custom domain for an API, and they all lead to this balancer which is of course very expensive and not needed for 95% of cases.

Comment: It is also super complex to setup while a CNAME is just made for this. I think there is a lot of room for other actors to create a way more simple Cloud provider for 80% of functionalities that are proposed by GAFAMs